# Must a matrix of which all conjugates have zero diagonal be zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ **real** matrix with the following property:

All the conjugates of $A$ have only zeros on the diagonal. Does $A=0$?

(By conjugates, I mean all the matrices similar to it, over $\mathbb{R}$, that is I require the conjugating matrix to be real).

---

Of course, if $A$ is diagonalizable, then clearly it must be zero.

The only idea I have is to use the [Jordan form for real matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices), but after some thought I am not sure this is a good approach.

Comment: What are the conjugates. The submatrices of some size?

Comment: @AnyAD: Conjugate in this context is another term for [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity).

Comment: @AnyAD Yes, I meant similar (over $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: You can triangulate the matrix over the reals, which shows $A$ has only the zero eigenvalue. Therefore it is nilpotent. Take a nonzero nilpotent matrix; does it have the property?

Comment: @AnyAD You are right of course. However, the requirement here is much stronger than having zero trace. So far, I could not come up with a  non-zero example.

Comment: @egreg Surely not all of them. I checked that the nilpotent matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is similar to a matrix with non-zero diagonal.

Comment: And every nilpotent matrix of size $2 \times 2$ is similar to that one. So at least the property is true for $n=2$.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think it is true: Suppose $A$ is nonzero. Then we find nonzero $v,w\in \mathbb R^n$ with $Av=w$. If $w$ and $v$ are linearly dependent, extend $v$ to a basis, then $A$ written in that basis will have a nonzero entry in the diagonal. If they are independent, then so are $v$ and $v+w$. Extending $\{v,v+w\}$ to a basis will then yield a nonzero diagonal element in $A$ written in this basis.

Comment: Elementary, elegant, love that

Answer (score 5):

An alternative, coordinate-based answer: Conjugate with the mutually inverse matrices $S^\pm_{ij}=\delta_{ij}\pm\delta_{i\alpha}\delta_{j\beta}$ for arbitrary $\alpha\ne\beta$ (that is, the matrices where $\pm1$ is added to the unit matrix in some off-diagonal entry) and consider the $\alpha$-th diagonal element of the result:

$$
\left.\sum_{jk}\left(\delta_{ij}+\delta_{i\alpha}\delta_{j\beta}\right)A_{jk}\left(\delta_{kl}-\delta_{k\alpha}\delta_{l\beta}\right)\right|_{i=l=\alpha}=\left.\sum_{jk}\left(\delta_{ij}+\delta_{j\beta}\right)A_{jk}\delta_{kl}\right|_{i=l=\alpha}=A_{\alpha\alpha}+A_{\beta\alpha}\;.
$$

Clearly $A_{\alpha\alpha}=0$ (from conjugating with the unit matrix), and since $\alpha\ne\beta$ were arbitrary, it follows that all entries of $A$ are zero.

Answer (score 5):

The field is unimportant. The given condition implies that $\operatorname{tr}(APDP^{-1}) = \operatorname{tr}(P^{-1}APD) = 0$ for every invertible matrix $P$ and every diagonal matrix $D$. Since the set of all diagonalisable matrices spans the whole matrix space (there is actually an even better result, namely, [every square matrix is the sum of at most three diagonalisable matrices](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0024-3795(99)00280-3)), the previous observation in turn implies that $\operatorname{tr}(AB)=0$ for every matrix $B$. Hence $A=0$.